# Wait for firestore queries to finish before return a cloud function response

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function that runs 3 firestore queries in 3 different collections. Each query has a foreach loop inside the then block and after the foreach loop it performs an update in a collection. Here is the code:

```
    const someDocRef
    const someDocRef2
    const someDocRef3

    db.collection("someOtherCollection").get().then(results=> {
       results.forEach(result=> {
          //do some work
       })
       someDocRef.update(....);
    })

    db.collection("someOtherCollection2").get().then(results=> {
       results.forEach(result=> {
          //do some work
       })
       someDocRef2.update(....);
    })

    db.collection("someOtherCollection3").get().then(results=> {
       results.forEach(result=> {
          //do some work
       })
       someDocRef3.update(....);
    })

    res.status(200).send("I waited for all the Queries AND the update operations inside the then blocks of queries to finish!");
```

So how can I return the response after all the operations finish?

Comment: What do you do exactly do with `someCollectionRefX.update(....)`?? `update()` is not a method of a `CollectionReference` but either of a `DocumentReference` or of a `WriteBatch`.

Comment: excuse me i meant docRef, I will change it

Comment: Ok, let me update my answer based on your update.

Answer (score 2):

If you call some asynchronous Firestore methods in your Cloud Function (like [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#get) for a `CollectionReference` or [`update()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#update) for a `DocumentReference`) you just have to chain the different promises returned by those methods.

So, based on the code of your question you could modify it as follows:

```
    const someDocRef
    const someDocRef2
    const someDocRef3

    db.collection("someOtherCollection").get()
    .then(results => {
       results.forEach(result=> {
          //do some work
       })
       return someDocRef.update(....);
    })
    .then(() => {    
       return db.collection("someOtherCollection2").get();
    })
    .then(results => {
       results.forEach(result=> {
          //do some work
       })
       return someDocRef2.update(....);
    })
    .then(() => {    
       return db.collection("someOtherCollection3").get();
    })
    .then(results => {
       results.forEach(result=> {
          //do some work
       })
       return someDocRef3.update(....);
    })
    .then(() => {    
       res.status(200).send("I waited for all the Queries AND the update operations inside the then blocks of queries to finish!");
    })
```

Note that this will work because the number of `someCollectionRefs` and `someDocRefs` is known upfront. In case you have a variable number of asynchronous operations to execute, you will need to use the `Promise.all()` method, as suggested in the other answers.

---

In case the 3 blocks

```
    db.collection("someOtherCollectionX").get()
    .then(results => {
       results.forEach(result=> {
          //do some work
       })
       return someDocRefX.update(....);
    })
```

can be executed totally separately (i.e. each block results does not impact the other blocks), you can parallelize the calls as follows:

```
    const someDocRef
    const someDocRef2
    const someDocRef3

    const p1 = db.collection("someOtherCollection").get()
    .then(results => {
       results.forEach(result=> {
          //do some work
       })
       return someDocRef.update(....);
    });

    const p2 = db.collection("someOtherCollection2").get()
    .then(results => {
       results.forEach(result=> {
          //do some work
       })
       return someDocRef2.update(....);
    });

    const p3 = db.collection("someOtherCollection3").get()
    .then(results => {
       results.forEach(result=> {
          //do some work
       })
       return someDocRef3.update(....);
    });

    Promise.all([p1, p2, p3])
    .then(() => {
        res.status(200).send("I waited for all the Queries AND the update operations inside the then blocks of queries to finish!")
    });
```

Comment: This should work but I think it has a drawback, they dont run in parallel. Isnt there a way to begin all the queries at the same time and just wait for them and their then block code to finish so i can send the response?

Comment: Yes, there is a way (`Promise.all()`) but it all depends on how the different calls are dependent on each others. Can the 3 blocks `db.collection("someOtherCollection").get().then(results=> {...
       someDocRef.update(....);
    })` be executed independently?

Comment: yes they can execute independently. Now each promise resolves to a promise since someDocRef.update() returns a promise. So i would need another promise all ?

Comment: As explained in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all, "The `Promise.all()` method returns a single Promise that resolves when all of the promises passed as an iterable have resolved". Indeed p1, p2 and p3 return a Promise, since `then()` returns a Promise and we return the Promise returned by `update()`. So you just have to build an array with p1, p2 and p3 and pass it to `Promise.all()` as shown in the answer.

Comment: @GiannisSavvidis You may accept my answer, if it solved your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use `Promise.all` to chain the promises. [Promise.all MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Promise Demo from MDN:

```
var promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
var promise2 = 42;
var promise3 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo');
});

Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then(function(values) {
  console.log(values);
});
// expected output: Array [3, 42, "foo"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to make your function an async function you could do something like this:

```
const someCollectionRef
const someCollectionRef2
const someCollectionRef3

const promise1 = db.collection("someOtherCollection").get().then(results=> {
   results.forEach(result=> {
      //do some work
   })
   someCollectionRef.update(....);
})

const promise2 = db.collection("someOtherCollection2").get().then(results=> {
   results.forEach(result=> {
      //do some work
   })
   someCollectionRef2.update(....);
})

const promise3 = db.collection("someOtherCollection3").get().then(results=> {
   results.forEach(result=> {
      //do some work
   })
   someCollectionRef3.update(....);
})
Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3])
  .then(_ => res.status(200).send("I waited for all the Queries AND the update operations inside the then blocks of queries to finish!"));
```

Comment: yes but this will return the response after the promises are resolved, right? the then block of each promise (which runs after the promise resolves I think) has for loops that i want to wait for them to finish and also the update operations which are asynchronous tasks as well. So how exactly I should use the promise.all ?

Comment: basically it's rinse and repeat, if the code inside your `then` is synchronous code then you're done with this, if not, then you'd probably need to return that promise (or a promise.all in case you have multiple asynchronous calls), then again that could become a bit of a callback hell so using functions to encapsulate common tasks + async/await should help a lot for readability

Comment: can I make a cloud function async so i can use await?